# Accoridon Menu Slide down and up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an Accordion Menu: https://jsfiddle.net/wfr57s57/

This is the JQuery Code

```
$(".menu-item").click(function(e) {
    var allContents = $(".menu-content");
    e.preventDefault();
        if(allContents.hasClass("activeMenu")) {
            allContents.removeClass("activeMenu");
        }
    var content = $(this).next().find(".menu-content");
    content.toggleClass("activeMenu");
});
```

It is working fine, but I want that, when one content is open, and I click on another menu-item, that the content is sliding up as it slided down before.

```
    <section>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                   Title
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="menu-content">
                        <div class="inner">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>

    <section>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                   Title
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="menu-content">
                        <div class="inner">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Also I don't know if this is the best solution - do you have a tip how to do it better?

Thank you :)

Comment: Maybe you should use the jquery accordion library ?

https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: How is your Accordion Menu built?  Did you use Bootstrap?  Version?

Comment: I used BS v3.3.7

Comment: How it is built - i just edited the post

Answer (score 0):

Try using heights instead of negative margin to hide/show

```
 .inner {
    height: 0;
}

 .activeMenu { //showContent
    min-height:200px;
```

Comment: thnx. I did want to avoid that, because I won't know the height of the content yet.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using jquery slideUp and slideDown?

```js
$(".menu-item").click(function() {
  if ($(this).next('.menu-outer').hasClass('opened')) {
    $(this).next('.menu-outer').slideUp().removeClass('opened')
  } else {
    $('.container.opened').slideUp().removeClass('opened')
    $(this).next('.menu-outer').slideDown().addClass('opened')
  }
});
```

```css
.menu-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 15pt;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: gray;
}

.menu-content {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu-outer {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          Title
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-outer container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="menu-content">
          <div class="inner">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
            sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
            et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          Title
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-outer container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="menu-content">
          <div class="inner">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
            sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
            et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Because I did not know there is a function like that. Amazing. Thank you for your time and your answert - it works :)